# Is there an alternative to using WorkflowMarkupSerializer's XmlSerializer to deserialize into a RuleSet object?

Tags: c#, performance, xmlserializer, rule-engine

I have an application which makes heave use of Microsoft's Rule Engine to run business rules.
As part of this we fetch the Rule Xmls from a DB  , Deserialize them using WorkflowMarkupSerializer class into RuleSet objects and then run the rule on vocabulary ...

We are using ScaleOut Distributing caching to Cache the Rule Xmls.

The Challenge is , every request needs a certain of number of the Rule Xmls to be DeSerialized into
RuleSet objects to run the RuleEngine and this Deserialization of Xmls is painfully slow.

I tried looking up the WorkflowMarkupSerializer class, and dont see any alternative to xml serializer ?
And the Workflow.Activities.Rules class is not binary serializable ....

Any ideas as to how to speed this up?

Comment: Have you investigated loading all the rules upfront and then caching until they are needed?

It would be helpful if you could provide the details of the approaches you have tried and be specific about why you believe the WorkflowMarkupSerializer is the bottleneck.

It is challenging to present options without more data.